# How to go one or more levels using os.chdir with '..''s as arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do I change path in Python using '..' to go down one or more levels as argument to os.chdir(). So that if I am on /home/usr/one and I want to go to 'home' directory a '../..' argument to chdir will do it. Do I wrap the argument in some other function?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly. `os.chdir('../../')` will bring you back two directories. This will change your working directory.

Comment: the py script I'm running on the terminal is not changing the directory in the terminal

Comment: `os.chdir` will not change the directory you are in in the terminal, it will only change it for the context inside the script. Why do you want to change it in the terminal?

Comment: I need automated utility for users.

Comment: If all the operations you are doing are in python, it doesn't matter that the directory doesn't change in the terminal, since it *will* change the working directory as far as Python is concerned.

Comment: So changing terminal directory is not possible in Python?

Comment: I am looking into it now, but I have not found a way to do so yet. I will update my answer if I figure out definitively whether it is possible or not.

Comment: I have asked the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39777348/3642398. I will update my answer if I learn anything from it that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in your question, if you are in the directory `/home/usr/one` `os.chdir('../../')` will bring you to `/home/`.

You can confirm this by calling:

```
os.getcwd()
```

Before and after changing directories. This function will show you the current working directory. Also, there is no need to wrap the argument to `chdir()` in another function.

## Edit:

Note that `os.chdir()` in a script will not change the directory you are in when you run the script from the terminal. In other words, if you are in `/home/usr/one` and run a script with `python myscript.py`, any directory changes made with `os.chdir()` within that script will not be refelected when the script finishes; you will still be in `/home/usr/one`.