# Change the current directory pwd, from the python script itself

Tags: python, bash

How to change the current directory of the command window from which a python script is invoked

I am writing a python script, that it should change directory (cd) of the current shell, to a specific directory, based on the user input.

The problem is everytime this script ends, I am back again to the original path, without changing.

```bash
bash-4.2$ pwd
/home/<username>/scripts
bash-4.2$ ./enterFW.py -fw <fw>
/filer/syslog_ng/2019/<fw>/2019/01/28  #<--I print the new directory, and it should be correct
bash-4.2$ pwd
/home/<username>/scripts #<-however after the script ends, i am back again to the original path
bash-4.2$
```

I change directory, using `subprocess.call(['cd', <new path>])`, or `os.chdir(<new path>)`...all are the same.

Please check, and advise

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-change-directory-cd-in-python

Comment: aha... you can add a startup script that does "cd /path"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to change directory and have change persist when script finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777348/possible-to-change-directory-and-have-change-persist-when-script-finishes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is actual workaround. Where you pick up the output of your 
script in current shell. Otherwise eveything gets executed in subshell.

### myprogram.py

```
import os
new_dir = "/home/cabox/workspace"
os.chdir(new_dir)
print os.getcwd()
```

---

In linux shell:

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/cliRtStocks$ pwd
/home/cabox/workspace/cliRtStocks

cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/cliRtStocks$ a=`python myprogram.py`;cd $a

cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ pwd
/home/cabox/workspace
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, and it works yes.. i did it in another way cd $(./enterFW.py -fw <fw> ), but it is the same.

I also looked for any ENV var that I can set to change the path like @PWD, but i failed....however this is enough for now